# Infinite tensor product of vector spaces as direct limit of finite families of vector spaces

Tags: vector-spaces, commutative-algebra, category-theory, tensor-products

I was looking for the infinite tensor product of vector spaces and in literature (for instance, Atiyah and Macdonald's book), I found it for algebras as the direct limit of finite families of algebras. I was particularly interested in vector spaces and found [these lecture notes very helpful.](https://www.fuw.edu.pl/~kostecki/scans/guichardet1969pt2.pdf) **The only problem is, I'm unable to understand the proof of the universal mapping, and therefore I've posted this question here, if someone can help me:**

Let $I$ be an infinite set and $\{E_i|i\in I\}$ be a family of vector spaces. For each $i\in I$, fix a non-zero $b_i \in E_i$. Define the following product:

> $\prod^t_{i\in I}E_i=\{(x_i)\in \prod_{i∈I}E_i|x_i = t_i$
>   for all but finitely many i}.
>
> Next, for each finite subset $J \subset I$, define the tensor product $E_J =
>  \bigotimes_{i∈J}E_i$ and for finite $J$ and $K$ such $J \subset K$, define the
>    maps $\varphi _{KJ} : E_J \to E_K$ as:  $$\varphi _{KJ} ((x_i)_{i \in
>  J}) =(\bigotimes_{i∈J}x_i)\otimes (\bigotimes_{i \in K-J} t_i).$$
>
> Then, $(E_J, \varphi _{KJ})_{J \subset K \subset I} $ is a directed
>   system of vector spaces and let  $(\bigotimes^t _{i\in I}E_i, \varphi _{J})_{J\subset I}$ be the direct limit of this system. Then $\bigotimes^t _{i\in
>  I}E_i$ is defined as the ***infinite tensor product*** of the family
>   $\prod^t _{i\in I}E_i$ ([see page 4](https://www.fuw.edu.pl/~kostecki/scans/guichardet1969pt2.pdf)).

If $\bigotimes^t _{i\in I}E_i$ is the tensor product of the family $\prod^t _{i\in I}E_i$, then it should satisfy the following universal property:

> For every vector space $F$ and multilinear mapping $u:\prod^t _{i\in I}E_i \to F$, there exists a unique linear mapping $V: \bigotimes^t _{i\in I}E_i \to F$ such that $V \circ \otimes=U$, where $\bigotimes:\prod^t _{i\in I}E_i \to \bigotimes^t _{i\in I}E_i$ is the tensor map.

In [page 5](https://www.fuw.edu.pl/~kostecki/scans/guichardet1969pt2.pdf) they proved the above universal property but I'm unable to understand. Can anybody make me understand the universal property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have a multilinear map $u$. Then for any finite $J\subset I$, you have the inclusion $\iota_J: \prod_{i\in J}E_i\to \prod_{i\in I}^tE_i$ (which sends $(x_i)_{i\in J}$ to $(y_i)$ with $y_i = t_i$ if $i\notin J$, $x_i$ else), and clearly $u\circ \iota_J$ is multilinear.

Therefore it factors as $\prod_{i\in J}E_i\to \bigotimes_{i\in J}E_i \overset{v_J}\to F$, by definition of the tensor product for a finite family of vector spaces.

Now we need to check that $v_J$ and $v_K$ are compatible if $J\subset K$. This is quite simple, indeed you have the following commutative diagram :

$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD} \prod_{i\in J}E_i @>>>\bigotimes_{i\in J}E_i \\
 @VVV @VVV \\
\prod_{i\in K}E_i @>>> \bigotimes_{i\in K}E_i @>>> F\end{CD}$

where the leftmost vertical arrows adds $t_l$'s for $l\notin J$, the other vertical arrow is $\varphi_{KJ}$. Moreover, the map $\prod_{i\in J}E_i\to \prod_{i\in K}E_i\to F$ is (it's easy to check) $u\circ \iota_J$.

It follows (by unicity in the universal property of the tensor product) that $\bigotimes_{i\in J}E_i\to \bigotimes_{i\in K}E_i\to F$ is $v_J$, but it's also $v_K\circ \varphi_{KJ}$.

So the $(v_J)$'s are compatible and therefore assemble into a map $\bigotimes_{i\in I}^tE_i \to F$

We now only have to check that $\prod_{i\in I}^t E_i\to \bigotimes^t_{i\in I}E_i \to F$ is $u$. But we can check that on each element of the restricted product, and each such element is of the form $y=\iota_J(x)$ for some $x$. Now if $y$ is of this form we have the following commutative diagram

$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} \prod_{i\in J}E_i @>>>\bigotimes_{i\in J}E_i@>>> F \\
 @VVV @VVV @V{id_F}VV \\
\prod_{i\in I}^tE_i @>>> \bigotimes_{i\in I}^tE_i@>>> F\end{CD}$

the rightmost square commutes by definition of the map $\bigotimes_{i\in I}^tE_i\to F$

Our goal is to show that the bottom arrows, applied to $y$, yield $u(y)$. But now this is the same as doing down then right-right on $x$. But by commutativity this amounts to doing right-right then down on $x$. But by definition this sends $x$ to $u\circ i_J(x) = u(y)$. So we are done.

(the uniqueness should be clear)

Comment: thanks for the elaboration but still I have a confusion regarding the restricted product. In the lecture notes they defined:
$∏^t_{i∈I}E_i$={${(x_i)∈∏_{i∈I}E_i|x_i=t_i}$  for all but finitely many i}, but this product is not vector subspace of the product $∏_{i∈I}E_i$. Right? That's why I thought the restricted product should be defined rather as $∏^t_{i∈I}E_i$={${(x_i)∈∏_{i∈I}E_i|x_i∈⟨t_i⟩}$  for all but finitely many i}. But, in the later case, **each element of the restricted product may not be of the form  $y=ι_J(x)$ for some x.** Isn't? Which product we are considering?

Comment: Also the left vertical maps between the product spaces which add $t_l$'s, are they linear? I suspect the construction of the infinite tensor product like this via direct limit if possible for vector spaces, do you think it's possible?

Comment: It doesn't matter that it's not a vector subspace, because we're not actually considering the vector space structure on the restricted product. We're looking at the vector space structures on the $E_i$'s somewhat independently : we're looking at multinilear maps out of the restricted product, not linear maps, so the vector space structure of the product never comes into question

Comment: As for the leftmost map, no, they are not linear, but again, it doesn't matter, all that matters is that if you compose with a multilinear map at the end, it stays multilinear, and that much is clear.

Comment: So to sum up : the restricted product in your notes is the correct one (where you have $t_i$), and the vector space structure on the restricted product (hence the linearity of the leftmost vertical maps) never comes into question ! Suppose you have a trilinear map $E\times F \times G\to K$. Can you see why the composite $E\times F \to E\times F \times G \to K$ is bilinear, where the first map is $(e,f)\mapsto (e,f,g)$ for any fixed $g\in G$ ?

Comment: Alright, I got it completely but want to confirm my following perceptions:

1. The transition maps $\varphi _J:⨂_{i∈J}E_i \to ⨂^t_{i∈I}E_i$ just adds $t_l$'s for $l \in I-J$?

2. $⨂:∏^t_{i∈I}E_i \to ⨂^t_{i∈I}E_i$ sends $(x_i)$ into $⨂x_i$ ?

3. Although my this question may not make any sense but can we say that $∏^t_{i∈J}E_i$ is the direct limit of the directed system of sets $(∏_{i∈J}E_i, ι_{KJ})_{J \subset K \subset I}$ ?, where the map $ι_{KJ}$ adds $t_l$'s from $j$ to $k$ components.

Comment: Yes to the 3 questions ! Question 3. allows to give a better explanation to question 2. actually

Comment: My last question: So one reason why researchers haven't paid much attention in the generalization of infinite tensor product could be that it's very gigantic but the direct limit technique yields less enormous but the underlying set on which the universal property is satisfied is not vector space. Therefore, the infinite tensor product defined in this way is not actually a tensor product, rather a generalization of tensor product.

Comment: I would guess the reason is more likely that it doesn't come up that often ;)

Comment: Can you please explain how the map $V:⨂^t_{i∈I}E_i→F$ is linear?

Comment: That's the universal property of the direct limit : compatible linear maps "assemble" into a linear map

Comment: So is there any theorem which says something like this: In any category the direct limit is the same whatever the connection maps are ? I see one can prove it like here the linearity of the direct limit can be proved easily from the connection maps but I'm curious if it's the case for any category (I can't see any counter example).

Comment: What do you mean "is the same" ?

Comment: I mean like here the direct limit is linear since the connecting maps were linear. In general, for instance, if the connecting maps preserve norm (in a category of normed spaces) then so does the direct limit? Or if they preserve the order (in the category of lattices) then so does the direct limit?

Comment: The definition of a direct limit is *defined* with respect to the category you're working in, so yes, *by definition* it does. Maybe what you have in mind is a specific *construction* of the direct limit in the category of sets, and you're wondering if it always applies ?

Comment: Yes exactly and now I got it. Thanku so much. I really appreciate you!